# Index Out of Range In A Recursive Call (Binary Search)

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search, outofrangeexception

I have been trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com) leetcode problem. The problem is to find range of a target value in a non-decreasing list. I am searching for a target value in a list using binary search, then 'ripling' out of that index as I exit the recursive call to see if here are any repeatted instances of that target and returning the range. My problem is the leetcode compiler is giving me a really bizzare index out of range error when I try to run the code. Here is my code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def searchRange(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """

        # Recursive Count (counts the number of recursive exits)
        RC = [0]
        length = len(nums) -1

        def getRange(left, right, nums):
            if(left == right):
                # Base case reached
                return [left, right]

            mid = (left + right) // 2
            indices = []

            # Searching for the middlle target index
            if (nums[mid] == target):
                indices = getRange(mid, mid, nums)
            elif (nums[mid] < target):
                indices = getRange(mid + 1, right, nums)
            elif (nums[mid] > target):
                indices = getRange(left, mid - 1, nums)
            
            # Ripling (as the program exits the last recursive call)
            if  indices[0] != 0 and nums[indices[0]] - RC[0] == target:
                indices[0] = indices[0] - 1
            elif indices[1] != length and nums[indices[1]] + RC[0] == target:
                indices[1] = indices[1] + 1

            RC[0] = RC[0] + 1
            return indices

        return getRange(0, length, nums)
```

And here is the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
    if (nums[mid] == target):
Line 22 in getRange (Solution.py)
    return getRange(0, length, nums)
Line 38 in searchRange (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().searchRange(param_1, param_2)
Line 66 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 76 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

It highlights line 22 as the problem. That is this line:

`if (nums[mid] == target):`

I don't understand why nums[mid] is out of range. The calculation for mid is a simple (left + right)/2, so for a list in non-decreasing order it should be imppossible for mid to go out of range. I have traced the iterations carefully with leetcode's input values and the program behaves exactly as I expect it to on paper.

At first I used the global variable for nums, and I thought that maybe the compiler was creating a new subsection of the nums array for every recursive call of the binary search algorithm, so I passed the original nums array into each recursive call. Unfortunately that did nothing to fix the problem.

Comment: This kind of issue is very easy to analyse with a debugger. Did you step through the code, inspecting variables, ...etc?

Comment: What happens if the given `nums` is an empty list?

Comment: Not your question, but your algorithm is not correct. What is your reasoning for doing `nums[indices[1]] + RC[0] == target`? This assumes that boundaries are only adapted with steps of 1, which certainly is not the principle of binary search...

Comment: To @trincot, I have tried executing the code in other environments but I haven't used a traditional debugger. I will give that a try.

Comment: I understood your use of `indices` (it is the pair to return), but the reasoning for using `RC` in that quoted expression is faulty. It assumes that the recursion depth corresponds to a shift in indices. This is not true, because by using `mid` you will most often adjust an index by more than 1 unit per recursion level, which is the whole point of using binary search (to not have to look at every single index, but make "jumps")

Comment: Thank you. I see your point and I will adjust it. Hopefully that will clear up the other issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

The direct cause for the error is that for an empty list as input, the check `left == right` will not be true and then your code goes on to access `nums[mid]`, which is invalid.

But taking a step back, your algorithm will not work. `RC` cannot help to update the `indices` correctly, as if you would only narrow down a list by steps of 1 (which is not what binary search does). Take for instance input `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` and finding 1...

What you need is two binary searches: one that will find the *start* of the sublist that has the targeted value, and another that will find the *end* of that same sublist.

Spoiler solution:

> `from operator import lt, le
>
>  class Solution(object):
>      def searchRange(self, nums, target):
>          def search(low, high, cmp):
>              while low < high:
>                  mid = (low + high) // 2
>                  if cmp(nums[mid], target):
>                      low = mid + 1
>                  else:
>                      high = mid
>              return low
>
>          i = search(0, len(nums), lt)  # find left-most occurrence
>          if i == len(nums) or nums[i] != target:  # not found
>              return [-1, -1]
>          return [i, search(0, len(nums), le) - 1]  # find right-most`

With `bisect` it becomes peanuts:

> `from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
>
>  class Solution(object):
>      def searchRange(self, nums, target):
>          i = bisect_left(nums, target)
>          if i == len(nums) or nums[i] != target:  # not found
>              return [-1, -1]
>          return [i, bisect_right(nums, target) - 1]`

Comment: While I think you have highlighted an important issue, the test case leetcode used was not an empty list. This is the input list: nums =  [5,7,7,8,8,10], and the target was 8.

Comment: I think you miss a point that your code case actually passed that test case, but failed the third one. Be aware that by default LeetCode executes three test cases, but as there is a runtime error on the third input, you don't get to see the results for the two first test cases (first one is OK, second one has wrong result). Delete the third test case, and you'll see the output for the first two test cases.

Comment: Are you sure you're interpreting the leetcode output right? The code seems OK for [5,7,7,8,8,10]: https://www.ideone.com/7TrK4U